# What is the best way to detect when a child process has terminated using signals

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, embedded-linux

I have a process child (created with fork), I want to know in the parent where it dies, and do there something. In the handle function I want to use member-class function, so I have to pass pointer to "this".

I have thought on two way:

***Option 1:***

use sigaction;

```
static RpcCmd* rpcCmdPtr = nullptr;// global pointer to save class
```

in the main:

```
  rpcCmdPtr  = this;  
  struct sigaction act;  
  memset(&act, 0, sizeof(act));  
  act.sa_handler = **sigchldHdl**;  
  sigaction(SIGCHLD, &act, 0)  

/* SIGCHLD handler. */  
void **sigchldHdl**(int sig)  
{  
  if(rpcCmdPtr != nullptr)  
  {  
    rpcCmdPtr->sigHandler(sig);  
  }  
}

void RpcCmd::sigHandler(int sig)  
{ // here are some code...}
```

***Option 2:***

use another thread, pass pointer to "this" as argument, and use there signalfd;

```
    static void * sigThread(void * arg)  
    {  
    rpcCmd* rpcCmdPtr = static_cast<rpcCmd*>(arg)  
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, NULL)  

    /* Create a file descriptor from which we will read the signals. */  
    sfd = signalfd (-1, &mask, 0);  

    while (1) {  
        struct signalfd_siginfo si;  
        res = read (sfd, &si, sizeof(si));  
        if (si.ssi_signo == SIGCHLD)  
            // more code ...  
    }
```

I want to know **WHAT** is the best way, and **WHY**?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take look at `std::signal`

Comment: So the question is really 'What is the best way to detect when a child process has terminated using signals?'  All this stuff about `this` is a complete red herring, I hope you see that now and perhaps edit the title of your question accordingly for future visitors / google searches.

Comment: @PaulSanders - If the title is not accurate then it is my blame.

Comment: @jww Not really - the question is very confused in general and needs rewriting.

Answer (score 3):

Read carefully [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) (and remember that most of C++ standard library -including `new`, [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), etc...- is based upon *non* async-signal-safe functions like `malloc`, so you usually cannot call these C++ functions from a signal handler)

You forgot the more portable option 3:

- at process initialization, create a [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) (to "self" process)
- before entering your [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) install a read handler for that pipe (it would [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) bytes from it)
- install (using [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html)) a signal handler for your signal that simply [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) one or a few bytes into the pipe. Notice that `write` *is* async-signal-safe.

This approach is proposed by Qt, see its [*Calling Qt Functions From Unix Signal Handlers*](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/unix-signals.html) page.

BTW, many event loop libraries (often above [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)...) do handle already `SIGCHLD`

Answer (score 1):

`option 1` is evil.

1. only [async-signal-safe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) function can be called inside a signal handler. And lots of function can't be called inside a signal handler, eg `malloc` `free` and `printf`
2. signal handler must be reentrant, your `RpcCmd::sigHandler` probably is not reentrant